# Is there a way to extract visual data from a folium map?

Tags: python, data-science, folium

I am constructing a map with meaningful data using Folium, on Python. But, I need to extract the information(for example an image which is bounded by max-min lat-long values). I tried several different ways. However, I don't get the data I desired.

A sample map, constructed using Folium, in an html file.
[image]
I need to use this as an RGB image rather than an interactive map. As much as I see, there is no such functionality. At least, I could not find. Is there a way?
Assuming that there is no such way, and I decided to crop this image using selenium browser method. So, I firstly had to indicate the boundaries in order to capture the image with corresponding latitude, longitude values. I applied fit_bounds(), but it is not bounded by given max/min lat-long values. There is padding-like expansion outside of the boundaries. Therefore, this way also failed. Could you please let me know if there is a solution for this purpose? Simply, briefly, I need to have the data that includes the RGB image, lat-long values(at least the boundaries) and these are retrieved directly from a folium map if possible.
Thank you in advance for any support.